# Return a value from a struct without specifying a property

Tags: c#, xml, struct

I have a question, and I have been looking for a while and I don't know if it is possible. I think I have seen it done before though.

So i have a struct.

```
public struct Field
{
    public String Name;
    public Int32 Size;

    public Field(String name, Int32 size)
    {
        Name = name;
        Size = size;
    }
}
```

What i want to do is when i use it below it returns the name value.

```
Field field = new Field("Ben", "1,70");

// name would receive the value Ben from the field.name variable
String name = field;
```

If you wise folk would know a way to get this to work, or maybe a better way it would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an [Implicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

<sub>***Note*** : Though its use is a little suspect in this case</sub>

```
public struct Field
{
   public String Name;
   public Int32 Size;

   public Field(String name, Int32 size)
   {
      Name = name;
      Size = size;
   }
   public static implicit operator string(Field d) => d.Name;
}
```

**Usage**

```
Field field = new Field("Ben", 1);
Console.WriteLine(field);
```

**Output**

```
Ben
```

Comment: Implicit operators should only be defined for widening conversions, though. This is a narrowing conversion. The `Name` field is right there. OP, you're better off just accessing it explicitly.

Comment: @madreflection i agree, its not really the *Bastion* of perfect design.

Comment: No I know, but it is more a is it possible.
The most simple on is indeed just accessing the Name property, but I was wondering.